# orthonormal basis question - linear algebra

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces, orthonormal

> Verify that $$v_1 = \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right), v_2=\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-2i\pi/3},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{2i\pi/3}\right), v_3=\left(\frac1{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{2i\pi/3},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-2i\pi/3}\right)$$
>   is an orthonormal basis for the complex inner product space $\Bbb C^3$.

I used the dot product as the standard inner product and assumed that the complex numbers were written in euler notation. I started by looking at the norms of each vector to make sure that they were 1. The norm of the first vector was 1, but when I looked at the second vector I had his problem:

$$\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}, -\frac 1{2\sqrt{3}}-\frac i2,-\frac 1{2\sqrt{3}}+\frac i2\right)\cdot \left(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}, -\frac 1{2\sqrt{3}}-\frac i2,-\frac 1{2\sqrt{3}}+\frac i2\right) = 0$$

so when I tried to find the square of the norm I got zero. Can anybody help me see where I have gone wrong? I have triple checked everything and still keep getting zero. I have the same problem with the third vector as the second two terms are just swapped.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please format your question so that it become readable. Right now it isn't.  http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Virtually unreadable. Please read up on how to format mathematics on this site. Use the Help menu.

Comment: I've tried and I don't know how, this was the best I could do. You do  not have to be so rude to me.

Comment: I've edited your question.  Make sure it is still correct.  BTW, no one was trying to be rude to you.  Reading improperly formatted questions is difficult and no one wants to hurt their eyes trying.  We expect a certain amount of effort from our questioners here and one of those expectations is that you will attempt a somewhat readable formatting of your equations with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thankyou so much, it is still correct.

Comment: @sam, if the norm of a vector is zero, and the norm is well defined, then the vector is zero.

Comment: HINT: It might (read: definitely will) be easier to multiply them out if you leave them in polar form.

Comment: @Zackkenyon if it is the zero vector then the three vectors provided cannot be a basis for $\Bbb C^3$ and the question is asking me to verify that it is an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb C^3$

Comment: that is clearly not the zero vector, was my point.

Comment: Ok so, this means I have done something wrong in my calculations to get the answer 0?

Comment: Yes.  That inner product is one.  HINT #2:  Don't forget to take the complex conjugate of the first vector (or second depending on how your professor defines the inner product on $\Bbb C^n$) when performing the inner product.

Comment: oh thank you! That's exactly what I missed! To take the conjugate! How silly of me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\|v_2\|^2 &= v_2\cdot v_2 \\ &=\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-2i\pi/3},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{2i\pi/3}\right)\cdot \left(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-2i\pi/3},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{2i\pi/3}\right) \\ &= \left(\overline{\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}}\cdot \frac 1{\sqrt{3}}\right) + \left(\overline{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-2i\pi/3}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{-2i\pi/3}\right) + \left(\overline{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{2i\pi/3}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}e^{2i\pi/3}\right) \\ &= \frac 13 + \frac 13e^{+2i\pi/3}e^{-2i\pi/3} + \frac 13e^{-2i\pi/3}e^{2i\pi/3} \\ &= \frac 13 + \frac 13 e^0 + \frac 13 e^0 \\ &= \frac 13 + \frac 13 + \frac 13 \\ &= 1\end{align}$$